# Crosstab in multiple Columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab, postgresql-9.3

Here am explain my problem with sample.

Its My Sample query.

```
SELECT * FROM public.crosstab(
$$VALUES ('na','sales', 1, 100) 
,('na','sales1', 1, 1000)
, ('ba','sales', 2, 300) $$
,$$VALUES ('1'), ('2')$$
) AS pivot (na text,n text, co11 int, col2 int)
```

It Produce Result like this

```
 Na N     Col1   Col2
 na sales  1000
 ba sales        300
```

But I want to get like this

```
Na   N    Col1   Col2
na  sales  100
na  sales1 1000
ba  sales         300
```

How to get that?. Why the above query produce that result?

am using **postgresql 9.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the answer: the missing `ORDER BY` clause. While using the two-parameter form of `crosstab()`, it's ok to use just `ORDER BY 1`. For the one-parameter form it would need to be

```
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Which never hurts, even with the two-parameter form. [The manual instructs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html#AEN153993)

> In practice the SQL query should always specify `ORDER BY 1,2` to ensure
>   that the input rows are properly ordered

Details:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this it produce the correct result

```
SELECT * FROM public.crosstab(
   $$VALUES ('na-sales', 'na','sales', 1, 100) 
   ,('na-sales1', 'na','sales1', 1, 1000)
   , ('ba-sales', 'ba','sales', 2, 300) order by 1,2 $$
,$$VALUES ('1'), ('2')$$
   ) AS pivot (t text, n text,na text, co11 int, col2 int)
```

Result

```
  t         N   Na    col1   col2
  na-sales  na  sales  100     
  na-sales1 na  sales1 1000
  ba-sales  ba  sales         300
```